# When passing start with 0 number getting error 400 Bad Request(SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 17)

Tags: node.js, api, swagger, body-parser

I am using swagger documentation for node js API 
my body model is

```
 TransferTokenRequest:
    required:
      - amount
      - currency
      - to
    properties:
      amount:
        description: "Number of amount to be transfer"
        type: number
        minimum: .00000001
        maximum: 100000000
```

When I am passing start with 0, number in body parameter in node js API then I am getting below error.

> **400 Bad Request**  Unexpected number in JSON at position 17

I am passing below request in PostMan

```
{
    "amount": 01
}
```

When I am sending a request to API then I am getting below Error response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 17
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/home/laxman/CODE/AKEO/LedgefarmNetworkAPi/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:84:17)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/laxman/CODE/AKEO/LedgefarmNetworkAPi/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:102:18
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (/home/laxman/CODE/AKEO/LedgefarmNetworkAPi/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:248:14)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/laxman/CODE/AKEO/LedgefarmNetworkAPi/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:294:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the code here that How are you passing JSON.

Answer (score 1):

A number can't start with a not significative 0. You can check it on [JSON Documentation Link](http://www.json.org/). So you should correct it manually in the value before passing. but in case if you can not update value manually then using REGEX, you can update the JSON value.

This should be invalid to pass the JSON like

```
{
  "amount": 01
}
```

So before passing the JSON, you can apply the code as:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(/ 0+(?![\. }])/g, ' '));
```

this will output as

```
{amount: 1}
```